# Update all properties for selected value in a DropDown

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following dropdown data-bound:

```html
<select data-bind="options: Value.DropDown.Options, 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   optionsValue: 'ID', 
                   optionsCaption: Value.DropDown.Name, 
                   value: Value.Selected.ID" disabled="disabled">
</select>
```

When I change the value it updates the binding for `ID` only. It doesn't change the other properties (in this case, `Name`):

**Example JSON**

```
[
   {
      "DropDown":
      {
         "ID":1,
         "Name":"Job Difficulty",
         "Options":
         [
            {
               "ID":1,
               "Name":"1",
            },
            {
               "ID":2,
               "Name":"2",
            },
            {
               "ID":3,
               "Name":"3",
            },
            {
               "ID":4,
               "Name":"4",
            }
         ]
      },
      "Selected":
      {
         "ID":1,
         "Name":"3",
      }
   }
]
```

`"Options"` is a collection of DropDownOptions that have an `ID`, `Name`, and a couple other properties. Selected is simply a single DropDownOption. Is there a way to bind the value of the select to change to that Option instead of just changing the `ID` of the option?

```html
<select data-bind="options: Value.DropDown.Options, 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   optionsValue: 'ID', 
                   optionsCaption: Value.DropDown.Name, 
                   value: Value.Selected" disabled="disabled">
 </select>
```

The above obviously doesn't work, as is, but added to help give an idea of what I want.

What is a way (preferably a automated way) to make all DropDowns (Selects) change other properties as well as ID when a new option is selected?

Comment: Your sample JS is JSON, does that imply you're using ko.mapping? If so  please include the code you use to create the ViewModels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of `value: Value.Selected.ID` and `optionsValue: 'ID'` tells knockout to only change that property (i.e. the value binding) to the currently selected `optionsValue` that is being masked by `optionsText: 'Name'`.

Without knowing the larger "picture" of what you are trying to achieve, to have an object be the "value" of the option, drop the `optionsValue: 'ID'` usage so it defaults to the `$data` object. The `value binding` will then become an observable that represents an "option" `{id: "", name: ""}`  See [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/RvS7X/).

**Step-wise evolution**:

So take the html:

```
<select>
    <option value="">I am really an empty string.</option>
    <option value="101010100101010">I look nice to the user.</option>
</select>
```

When moving that out to knockout, we would setup an array and bind to it:

```
 var data = [{text: "I am really an empty string.", value: ""},
  {text: "I look nice to the user.", value: "101010100101010"}]
```

The most verbose binding methodology (`foreach`):

- Using a text mask for a single property value which is equivalent to our original html:

  ```
  <select data-bind="foreach: data, value: somePropertyOrObservable">
    <option data-bind="text: text, value:  value"></option>
  </select>
  ```
- However, now we can go more advanced an actually pass objects as the value

  ```
  <select data-bind="foreach: data, value: somePropertyOrObservable">
    <option data-bind="text: text, value:  $data"></option>
  </select>
  ```

Furthermore, Knockout provides the handlers on `<select>` for some nice [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). The above become (respectfully)

```
<select data-bind="options: data, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value: somePropertyOrObservable"></select>

<select data-bind="options: data, optionsText: 'text', value: somePropertyOrObservable"></select>
```

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. Thank you for the explanation and not just an example. (Though the example was nice too.)

Comment: @Shelby115 I provided a more in-depth "evolution" from raw html to final knockout setup to illustrate, hopefully more clearly, what is going on "behind the scenes".

Comment: Alright, thank you. I hope you didn't take my first comment as sarcasm because that was not the case haha.

Comment: @Shelby115 Not at all.

Comment: So I figured out (thanks to your help) what was causing me problems. For some reason one of my properties are just going missing at random times. (That property being Selected). If I set value of the select to `Value.Selected.ID` it is displayed in the span (like the span in your example). But if I do just `Value.Selected` it's completely missing. Any ideas as to why that's happening? The data is being passed correctly from the controller.

Comment: Here's a more accurate example to what my setup is like: http://jsfiddle.net/EM9Rh/54/ The example works but when I do `value: Value.Selected` in my actual view the `"Selected": { <value> }` goes missing from the display span (regardless of the selection).

Comment: I've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485718/json-property-going-missing if you don't mind helping.